# Why is my Neo4j IN returning false for all results?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query:

```
MATCH (a)-[r1]-(b) WITH a, b, 
COLLECT(b.primaryId) AS bAll, r1
MATCH (b)-[r2]-(c)
RETURN c.primaryId IN bAll
```

In particular, what I'm after here is depth 2 connections that are also depth 1 connections, i.e. if A relates to B and C, and B and C relate to each other.

This is returning only `false`. However, when I return `c.primaryId, bAll` I can clearly see some overlap in the values. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Including Sample Response

```
╒═══════╤═════════╕
│"id(c)"│"bAll"   │
╞═══════╪═════════╡
│1077598│[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│195687 │[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│461579 │[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1084085│[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1295819│[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│316503 │[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1505256│[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1494600│[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│708871 │[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│319671 │[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│957553 │[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│394705 │[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│379116 │[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1017683│[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│330049 │[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│567549 │[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│344636 │[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1102414│[902604] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│598267 │[540185] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│829725 │[540185] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1010574│[540185] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1437190│[540185] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1094878│[540185] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│19008  │[540185] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1084085│[540185] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│366066 │[282808] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1443101│[282808] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│433507 │[282808] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1514110│[282808] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1456009│[282808] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│146294 │[282808] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│29812  │[282808] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│889369 │[282808] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│221085 │[282808] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1084085│[282808] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│17122  │[282808] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│79762  │[282808] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│887829 │[282808] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│375676 │[282808] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1071899│[282808] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1632753│[282808] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1084085│[1748723]│
├───────┼─────────┤
│1071899│[1748723]│
├───────┼─────────┤
│710990 │[1748723]│
├───────┼─────────┤
│402609 │[269346] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1711007│[269346] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1408844│[269346] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│327082 │[269346] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1575549│[269346] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│165601 │[269346] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│886370 │[269346] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│560737 │[269346] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1084085│[269346] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│935787 │[269346] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1448889│[269346] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│644901 │[269346] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1415535│[269346] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1713087│[269346] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1084085│[122631] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│1384573│[122631] │
├───────┼─────────┤
│268383 │[1071899]│
├───────┼─────────┤
│1084085│[1071899]│
├───────┼─────────┤
│1748723│[1071899]│
├───────┼─────────┤
│282808 │[1071899]│
└───────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: Can you post a sample data set?

Comment: Included a sample response for `RETURN c.primaryId, bAll`

Comment: It is not at all clear what result you want to get. Show a short example of nodes and relationships, and the desired result.

Comment: I suppose the problem is if you look above, you'll notice that the second column is supposed to be a list. But it's not. And I couldn't figure out why not. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Aggregation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) functions like `COLLECT` aggregate over a "grouping key". In your query, `WITH a, b, COLLECT(b.primaryId) AS bAll, r1` is using the combination of `a`, `b`, and `r1` as the grouping key, so the `bAll` aggregation will always only contain a single `primaryId` value (from the `b` node in the same group).

The following may be closer to what you wanted. It returns, for each node `a`, the `primaryId` values of all depth-2 nodes that are also depth-1 nodes. (The query makes the simplifying assumption that your nodes have unique `primaryId` values.)

```
MATCH (a)--(b)
WITH a, COLLECT(b) AS bs
UNWIND bs AS b
MATCH (b)--(c)
WHERE c IN bs
RETURN a, COLLECT(c.primaryId) AS cIds;
```

[UPDATE]

If you also want to return all `r1` relationships, you can do this:

```
MATCH (a)-[r1]-(b)
WITH a, COLLECT(r1) AS r1s, COLLECT(b) AS bs
UNWIND bs AS b
MATCH (b)--(c)
WHERE c IN bs
RETURN a, r1s, COLLECT(c.primaryId) AS cIds;
```

Comment: I see, this is definitely working more correctly, I see the list is now something more sensible. However, suppose I still want to return `r1` at the end of the query, if I do things this way it tells me `r1` is not defined from the `WITH` clause onwards.

Comment: I also fixed some issues in my answer.

Comment: This makes sense now